# Ipython Notebook: where is jupyter_notebook_config.py in Mac?

Tags: python, macos, ipython, jupyter-notebook, ipython-parallel

I just started using a Mac, so please forgive me if this sounds too naive.

I'm trying to install `Interactive Parallel`. From https://github.com/ipython/ipyparallel, it says I need to find `jupyter_notebook_config.py`.

I've already installed python and related packages with `Anaconda`, and I can use the ipython notebook. But when I search with `spotlight` for `jupyter_notebook_config.py`, I just can't find this file:

[image]

So, where can I find this file?

UPDATE: this is my `home` folder:

[image]

There is only `anaconda`.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Look in your home directory for a `.jupyter` folder.
It should contain the file according to the [docs](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/Notebook/Configuring%20the%20Notebook%20and%20Server.html):

> The notebook web server can also be configured using Jupyter profiles
> and configuration files. The Notebook web server configuration options
> are set in a file named jupyter_notebook_config.py in your Jupyter
> directory, which itself is usually .jupyter in your home directory.

If the `.jupyter` folder does not contain a `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file, you need to generate it with `jupyter notebook --generate-config`. For Jupyter lab, you use the command `jupyter lab --generate-config` to generate the `jupyter_lab_config.py` file.

Comment: I only find `anaconda`. Is `.jupyter` hidden? How can I disply it?

Comment: @cqcn1991 Yes the dot means, that the folder is hidden. [Here](http://www.macworld.co.uk/how-to/mac-software/how-show-hidden-files-in-mac-os-x-finder-3520878/) is an article explaining how to show hidden files in MacOS X.

Comment: Ok, my fault. I should generate it first using `jupyter notebook --generate-config`

Comment: @cqcn1991 Lol thanks, your own comment helped me much more than anything I've found on the internet.

Answer (score 17):

try this command:

```
jupyter --paths
```

http://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html

Comment: Excellent, this worked for me; while `.jupyter` folder did not have the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file, I did find it in one of the paths listed here

Answer (score 1):

As cqcn1991 said, you first need to generate the config file.

After drilling down from my home path here's where I found the executable to generate the config file and how I generated it.

I also had to reference the jupyter executable file with ./ as I apparently don't have that in my path just yet but will add it.

```
cd /Users/myMac/anaconda2/bin
 ./jupyter notebook --generate-config
Writing default config to: /Users/myMac/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py
```

Then I did find the config file in my home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Should you Uninstalling Anaconda for that :

```
$ herm -rf ~/anaconda3re

$ conda install anaconda-clean

$ anaconda-clean

$ anaconda-clean --yes

$ export PATH="/Users/jsmith/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

That's Solve my problem On mac ;
For more information visite : https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/

Comment: Doesn't look like a valid answer.