# Open jupyter notebook in Opera on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, jupyter

I've set up jupyter notebook to open in Opera on Ubuntu (Chrome and lastpass don't work well with jupyter).  I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35229604/how-to-change-the-default-browser-used-by-the-ipython-jupyter-notebook-in-linux) guide.

However, when I open jupyter notebook from the terminal, it takes me to `http://openurl%28http//localhost:8888/tree,new-page)` instead of `http://localhost:8888/tree`.

The proper url is still opened fine on Chrome.  Running Anaconda Python 3 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Set this in your jupyter_notebook_config.py (assuming you installed Opera in /usr/bin)

```
c.NotebookApp.browser = '/usr/bin/opera %s'
```

Comment: Fixed a problem that was a real pain for me. Jupyter Notebook now opens Opera like a charm. Adding the %s was the key.

Comment: The "%s" works for windows as well, thank you!  
`  `  
`c.NotebookApp.browser = 'C:/Program Files/Opera/launcher.exe %s'`

Comment: For someone who's new to Anaconda or Jupyter notebooks, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32626312/5968979)'s how to find the `jupyter_notebook_config.py` file

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue (https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1832), disabling the turbo mode might help.

Comment: Thanks, but turbo mode was already off.  No difference if it was on or off.